# Recursively find the root squared sum

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to recursively find the root squared sum of two arrays. Basically given:

```
array1 = {1,5,8};
array2 = {2,9,10};
RSS = sqrt((1-2)^2 + (2-5)^2 + (3-8)^2) = 4.58258
```

I have implemented the following code, but after testing I know that it does not work. I am returning the square root each time, so my RSS value is lower than it should be.

```
double findRSS(int* array1, int* array2, int size){
    double sum = 0;
    if (size <= 0){
        return 0;   }
    else{
        sum = pow((array1[size-1] - array2[size-1]), 2);
        sum = sum + findRSS(array1, array2, size-1);
    }
    return sqrt(sum);
}
```

For the above example I am returning 2.85011 instead.

I feel I am close but just have a small issue. Can someone help me out?

Comment: This shouldn't compile nor should you use a recursion. Can't you just make a simple for loop?

Comment: This does compile. I know I can use a for loop but I am trying to do this recursively.

Comment: Should `sum = sum + (array1, array2, size-1)` be `sum = sum + findRSS(array1, array2, size-1)`

Comment: Since you want to take the square root of the sum of squared terms, you can call the recursive function from main this way `sqrt(findRSS(array1, array2, size)` and in `findRSS` simply return the `sum` at the end (doesn't need to be double) not `sqrt(sum)`.

Comment: I want my function to return the square root of the sum though. I understand I can call the function like that in main. I am trying to see if there is a way to recursively find the RSS and return it from a function.

Comment: This is the recursive way where the role of the function is to return squared sum of all the terms. For the given input, your code is doing `sqrt(sqrt(sqrt((1-2)^2) + (5-9)^2) + (8-10)^2)`

Comment: You can do that, but it will involve plenty of pointless square roots that are undone immediately again by squaring. All you need to do is square the return value of the recursive `findRSS` call.

Comment: in the above example, this just results in the sum. not the square root of the sum. @MaxLanghof

Comment: He means replace `sum = sum + findRSS(array1, array2, size-1);` with `sum = sum + pow(findRSS(array1, array2, size-1),2);`. That way you only have one un-canceled square root at the top of the recursion tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calculating sqrt((1-2)^2 + sqrt((2-5)^2 + sqrt((3-8)^2)))
you can do somewhat simple "fix" to your logic by squaring recursed result once

```
double findRSS(int* array1, int* array2, int size){
    double sum = 0;
    if (size <= 0){
        return 0;   }
    else{
        sum = pow((array1[size-1] - array2[size-1]), 2);
        sum = sum + pow(findRSS(array1, array2, size-1), 2); // you are undoing sqrt for new one
    }
    return sqrt(sum);
}
```

but as you can see the method is flawed. This is a good example of why structured development is important. You can find principles developers found that aged well here: http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch01s06.html

so your methods would become something like this:

```
double diffSum(int* array1, int* array2, int size, int power) {
    double sum = 0;
    if (size <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        sum = pow((array1[size - 1] - array2[size - 1]), power);
        sum = sum + diffSum(array1, array2, size - 1, power);
    }
    return sum;
}

double findRSS(int* array1, int* array2, int size) {
    return sqrt(diffSum(array1, array2, size, 2));
}
```

key to success is when to know you need to separate; beware keeping methods with fewer lines helps on maintaining the code

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want:

```
double findRSS(int* array1, int* array2, int size){
    double sum = 0;
    if (size <= 0){
        return 0;   }
    else{
        sum = pow((array1[size-1] - array2[size-1]), 2);
        sum = sum + pow(findRSS(array1, array2, size-1), 2);
    }
    return sqrt(sum);
}
```

Write out the math by hand to verify that it is correct.

But please don't write actual programs this way. Not only is this a needlessly convoluted way to write a trivial loop, it is also horribly inefficient to take a square root at every iteration/recursion just to immediately undo it at the next. Even for the simple version below, the single square root at the end will take longer than everything else together:

```
double findRSS(int* array1, int* array2)
{
  double sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    sum += std::pow(arra1[i] - array2[i], 2);
  return std::sqrt(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean this way:

```
int findRSS(int *arr1, int *arr2, int size)
{
    if (size == 0)
        return 0;
    return (int)pow(arr1[size - 1] - arr2[size - 1], 2) + findRSS(arr1, arr2, size - 1);
}

int main()
{
    int arr1[] = { 1, 5, 8 };
    int arr2[] = { 2, 9, 10 };
    cout << sqrt(findRSS(arr1, arr2, 3)) << endl;
}
```